# Econ stack exchange versus math stack exchange

Tags: discussion

I know this not a perfect question. But I think that math stack exchange works better than Econ stack exchange because more people on math stack exchange are helpful, gentle and wise and give more clear, workable, wise answers even they don’t solve all question. (I don’t require nad encourage solving all question) but their hints are more understandable and workable. I even get more useful answers on economics questions in compare to this Econ stack website. Thus, people prefer to ask for their question in math exchange. And Econ stack cannot become popular in comperation to math stack, and will not anymore...

I read your comments in previous questions. You want this website to contribute to future, but this never realize. I can foresee this . All I want to say is this! You may disagree with me, no problem, it’s okay, it depends on you...

Regards...

Answer (score 2):

I have downvoted your post because I do not agree with your assessments (this is how voting on the meta-site works), but thank you for sharing your opinion for this site with us. Feedback is always important, especially negative feedback.

Just a note: we are not in any kind of competition with math.se.

Comment: +1 for sharing your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: And I can see there is no competition, but I just want to share my opinion about the imporevment in the math se., but I couldn’t see this in this website. Thus I made such a competition. Ps: this does not hold for all users. I spoke in general.